# Can't Cannot resolve constructor 'SlideModel(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'?

Tags: java, android-studio, androidimageslider

**I want to add auto slider image with indicator using image link inside my android application, but the error i got is here**

```
Cannot resolve constructor 'SlideModel(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
```

***Main Activity***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.denzcoskun.imageslider.ImageSlider
    android:id="@+id/image_slider"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    app:iss_auto_cycle="true"
    app:iss_period="1000"
    app:iss_delay="0"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

***Main Activity java***

```
package com.example.imageslider;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import com.denzcoskun.imageslider.ImageSlider;
import com.denzcoskun.imageslider.models.SlideModel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity<val> extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageSlider imageSlider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    imageSlider = (ImageSlider) findViewById(R.id.image_slider);
    final List<com.denzcoskun.imageslider.models.SlideModel> remoteImg = new ArrayList<>();

    remoteImg.add(new SlideModel(R.drawable.banner_img, "The animal population decreased by 58 
    percent in 42 years."));

    }
 }
```

I am a beginner in Android Studio Please help me to fix this problem. I will be very
Thanks for them

Comment: remove the new word when you add to the list then let me know if it not working

Comment: I edit your question copy and paste it and then try.

Comment: I edit it you can check it

Comment: Still facing same error ..?

Comment: you can paste this after adding it to the list                                 imageSlider.setImageList(imageList, ScaleTypes.FIT);

Answer (score 0):

- Use version '**0.0.6**' of **denzconkun:ImageSlideshow**

  `dependencies { implementation 'com.github.denzcoskun:ImageSlideshow:0.0.6' }`

https://youtu.be/1AS5HcXPpqk

Comment: It isn't really clear that this is answering the question - it seems to just be recommending a different library instead

Comment: @DavidW It is not a different library. In the above code he has already used the denzconkun:ImageSlideshow. I also faced to the same problem when I used the new version of it. So I recommended to use the 0.0.6 version of the same library.

Comment: Fair point my mistake - I think a bit of explanation (maybe a link to the bug that was fixed, or even an indication of where your "dependencies" lines should go) would make this a more useful answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
remoteImg.add(
  new SlideModel(R.drawable.banner_img, 
    "The animal population decreased by 58 percent in 42 years.", 
    ScaleTypes.FIT)
 );
```

instead of

```
remoteImg.add(
  new SlideModel(R.drawable.banner_img, 
  "The animal population decreased by 58 percent in 42 years.")
);
```

as the constructor have three variables

Answer (score 0):

Hi this will help you make sure you have the latest library of denzconkun:ImageSlideshow then do it like this

```
ImageSlider imageSlider= findViewById(R.id.slider);

    List<SlideModel> slideModels=new ArrayList<>();
    //If you want the one with the title do it like this
    slideModels.add(new SlideModel("https://picsum.photos/id/894/300/200","Image 1",ScaleTypes.FIT));
    slideModels.add(new SlideModel("https://picsum.photos/id/892/300/200","Image 2",ScaleTypes.FIT));
    slideModels.add(new SlideModel("https://picsum.photos/id/891/300/200","Image 3",ScaleTypes.FIT));
    //If you don't want the title do it like this
    slideModels.add(new SlideModel("https://picsum.photos/id/894/300/200",ScaleTypes.FIT));
    slideModels.add(new SlideModel("https://picsum.photos/id/892/300/200",ScaleTypes.FIT));
    slideModels.add(new SlideModel("https://picsum.photos/id/891/300/200",ScaleTypes.FIT));
    imageSlider.setImageList(slideModels,ScaleTypes.FIT);
```